# Generating new maps like the image in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, downscaling

[image]

I have two maps that look like **a** and **b**. I need to convert them into like **c** and **d**.

I have created fishnet using ArcGIS but confused about the latter part.

Comment: Hi, have you looked into down-sampling algorithms? Usually you can provide a grid (e.g. the grid from c/d).

Comment: I have tried downsampling, but It misses a lot of areas from the selected region.

Comment: Create your fishnet, use that in a zonal stats tool to compute min/mean/max within each fishnet cell, then join that table back to the fishnet and symbolise.

Comment: @Hornbydd Thanks for your guidance. It worked